# Preprocess the Linux source code and save to another directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, kernel, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have the entire Linux source code in /tmp/linux-src. After menuconfig I want to do "some kind of gcc -E" where all the preprocessor macros other than #include are expanded so the *actual configured preprocessed* source code (for compilation) will be saved in /tmp/linux-src-to-compile - not in single file but rather keeping the whole tree structure leaving out the files that are not needed. Is this kind of trickery possible? Is it also possible when prepping for cross-compilation?

Thanks

Comment: What does "other than `#include`" mean here? How else would macros get defined?

Comment: there are several ways.  IMO: the easiest way is to write a `makefile` the does all the work for you

Comment: I recommend asking it on https://unix.stackexchange.com, it fits best to the question topic

Comment: Can you clarify the motivation/goal for this ? it might be possible to come up with a workaround of partial solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: NO. It can not be done for a general case.

Long Answer:
Most of the pre-processing occurs via #include files. Keeping the #include (without expanding them) will prevent most #define, #ifdef, ... from working.

Consider the simple case of `SEEK_END`

```
file.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) ;
```

Translation of SEEK_END to '2' will require reading, analyzing and expanding `stdio.h`, following many `#if`, etc. Also, it will require expanding any previously #included files, which might define symbol that will impact `stdio.h` - stdlib.h in this case.